# preg_replace / regular expression help

Tags: php, regex

I need to strip unwanted characters from a string. I want to use preg replace, but I am useless at regular expressions.

My string should only allow a-z A-Z 0-9 and spaces. No other characters.

So for example:

```
some string's-are#bad
```

would become:

```
some stringsarebad
```

Many thanks

Comment: did you read the PHP documentation? There is an example EXACTLY like that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 ]/i', '', $string);
```

To explain this:

- `/` opening delimiter -- start the regex
- `[^` start negative character group -- match anything except what's in this selection
- `a-z0-9` match alphabetic and numeric characters and spaces
- `]` close character group
- `/` closing delimiter
- `i` case insensitive search -- match `A-Z` as well